# MySQL date function - Can you check their output without a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been given a query to optimise recently and it looks like it's doing much more than it needs to.

Anyway, one section of the query seems redundant to me and I just wanted to make sure it wasn't doing more that I think it's doing:

```
    WHERE orders.`date` > 
        DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH),"%Y-%m-01") 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY),"%Y-%m-01")
```

From my understanding the first `DATE_FORMAT()` should be outputting 1st of last month, however, I can't make any sense out of the second `DATE_FORMAT()` function as it's already specifying the day in the first one???

My question is either can someone shed some light (if there is any) on the above, or tell me how I can check the output of MySQL functions?

Thanks!

Comment: The second `WHERE` clause after the `AND` appears to do nothing.

Comment: I thought so too, I just wanted to make sure it didn't have some random use that wasn't apparent. Thanks @AeroX.

Comment: The second one is equivalent to `AND TRUE` (if the system clock is correct).

Comment: So, it's more of a systems check rather than to do with the query itself, @Vatev?

Comment: MySql knows that this condition always evaluates to true, and is able to optimize this condition (simply removes it from the `WHERE` clause). You can remove this condition from the query, but it does not affect the query performance, or maybe only a bit - a few miliseconds during the parse phase.

Comment: @RossWilson it is an error. I'm not sure it is possible for `DATE_FORMAT` to return a falsy value for the current time with that format (even if the clock is set to a weird time). If it is possible, it doesn't make any sense to rely on it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for you help, @Vatev . It's from a piece of code that was put in place years ago, however, the system I'm working with has a number of random bits of code that are very, VERY poor but removing them causes problems elsewhere. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't doing anything strangly essential before I got rid of it. :p

Comment: Thank you as well, @kordirko. I would have included you in the comment above, but SO doesn't like it :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check a result of this function, just do:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY),"%Y-%m-01");
```

To be sure if this condition really always evaluates to true, just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY),"%Y-%m-01");
```

you will see, that results (count) of both queries will be the same,
see demo: --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03c4d/3

---

MySql during a parse phase identifies constant expressions, and removes expressions that evaluates to true.
 Details are described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/where-optimizations.html.

To check that MySql really removes this condition, perform these commands:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT * FROM some_table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY),"%Y-%m-01");

SHOW WARNINGS;
```

This displays something like this:

```
/* select#1 */ select `test`.`some_table`.`x` AS `x` 
               from `test`.`some_table` where 1
```

Pay attention to `where 1` - the whole condition in the query has been simplified to 1 (true).

Answer (score 0):

The first DATE_FORMAT returns the 1st of last month and the other one returns the 1st of the month yesterday belonged to.

I think this maybe a typo - it would make sense if it was a range (e.g. BETWEEN) the first DATE_FORMAT and the second so it only returns last months data for instance

You can display the output of the functions with

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY),"%Y-%m-01");
```